# change sqlserver id session after connection close

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

i have a doubt about the sql sessions in .net.

why when i close the sql connection after it has the same id session and pid?

i tried with this test:

```
        public void c() 
        {
            SqlConnection conn = null;
            SqlCommand comm = null;
            SqlDataReader data = null;
            String q;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    conn = new SqlConnection("Server=server;Database=db;User id=user;Password=pass;timeout=10");
                    conn.Open();

                    q =
                    "select connection_id,s.session_id " +
                    "from sys.dm_exec_connections c " +
                    "join sys.dm_exec_sessions s on s.session_id = c.session_ID " +
                    "where s.session_id=@@spid";
                    comm = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
                    data = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    while (data.Read())
                       Console.WriteLine(data[0] + "-" + data[1]);

                    comm.Dispose();
                    data.Dispose();
                    conn.Dispose();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                if (comm != null)
                    comm.Dispose();
                if (data != null)
                    data.Dispose();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

what i have to do to close everytime the session?

thank in advance!

!! RESOLVED !!
i inserted in the connection string "Pooling=true;", then is:

```
conn = new SqlConnection("Pooling=true;Server=server;Database=db;User id=user;Password=pass;timeout=10");
```

Comment: Closing a connection is handled by ADO.Net not the sql server. All it does is return the connection to the pool, it doesn't really close anything.

Comment: You can use ClearPool option OR keep Pooling = False in connection string which will create new connection everytime you connect.

Comment: You can clear the pool but you will kill performance. Don't do it unless you really have to for some reason. The standard pattern is to just close it for a reason.

Comment: @user3061212 Please **_do not_** edit your question to include the answer. Instead, answer the question yourself, and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Your edit doesn't resolve anything at all. Pooling is enabled by default. The code though is very bad - you create a new connection in a loop but may or may not close it when finished. Don't do that. Just wrap the connection in a `using` statement and let .NET dispose it automatically. A simple` using (var conn=new SqlConnction(...){...}` is enough